# Number of ways to interleave identical ordered sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

How many ways to interleave three identical sequences (X,Y,Z) keeping the relative order? Possible ways are such as XYZXYZXYZ, XXXYYYZZZ and etc., as long as you can pick out 3 groups of XYZ with the order.

This question comes from my son's middle school math contest. For this particular problem, I was able to use back track and recursive approach to get the answer which is 42. But I feel there might be a more general and simple approach given the answer happens to be 7x6.

Comment: How long are the sequences?

Comment: When $n$ copies of the sequence $XY$ are interleaved, this gives the Catalan numbers, I believe. So this is a generalization. Besically, you want the number of paths from $(0,...,0)\in\mathbb N^m$ to $(n,n,...,n)$ subject to the condition that every node $(a_1,a_2,...,a_m)$ satisfies $a_1\leq a_2\leq ...\leq a_m$ and each step increments one value.

Comment: (That last under the assumption that your sequence is of distinct objects - that is $X\neq Y, Y\neq Z, X\neq Z$.

Comment: I think this is the same as enumerating $3\times 3$ [Young's Tableaux](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau). i.e. how may ways are there to fill $$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|}\hline X &\phantom{5} &\phantom{5} &\phantom{5}\\\hline  Y& \phantom{5}&\phantom{5} &\phantom{5}\\\hline Z&\phantom{5} &\phantom{5} &\phantom{5} \\\hline\end{array}$$ with $\{1,2,\ldots ,9\}$ such that rows increase left to right and columns increase top to bottom. The numbers 1 to 9 are locations for X,Y and Z. The link contains the hook length formula to calculate this which gives 42.

Comment: That is: elements from $\{1,2,\ldots , 9\}$ are chosen without replacement to fill the grid.

Comment: Thanks for the education about the Young's Tableaux and the Hook Length Formula. Very interesting! Is there any intuitive explanation for the special case of the original problem, using middle school combinatorics?

Comment: I doubt it - even the simple case of Catalan numbers is probably too advanced for middle school.

Comment: I think the easiest way is to count the number that start with $XX$. Then, by the Young Tableaux argument, that is exactly half of them, because of the symmetry of the $3\times 3$ case. I think, for middle school, though, even that might be too deep, and a complete count might be all that you can do.

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment, but not a complete answer.

It looks like the general formula might be:

$$\frac{1}{\binom{n+1}{1}\binom{n+2}{2}\cdots\binom{n+m-1}{m-1}}\frac{(nm)!}{n!^m}$$

when interleaving $n$ identical sequences of length $m$.

Note that, by the Young Tableau argument in comments, this would have to be symmetric in $m,n$. Surprisingly, this formula is symmetric, since it can be rewritten as:

$$(nm!)\frac{1!2!3!...(m-1)!1!2!\dots (n-1)!}{1!2!\cdots(n+m-1)!}$$

---

**How I came to this conjecture**

In short: Brute force number crunching, with some hope that it was like Catalan numbers.

Working on the basis that this is "like" the Catalan numbers, I tried the case of $n$ sequence of three elements, $X,Y,Z$, and the theory that the value is of the form:

$$\frac{1}{f(n)}\frac{(3n)!}{n!^3}$$

As it turns  out, $f(n)$ is, for the first 21 values, at least, always an integer, and, according to OEIS, they match the "[Pentagonal pyramidal numbers](https://oeis.org/A002411)", so that we might conjecture that $f(n)=(n+1)^2(n+2)/2$.

$$\begin{matrix}
n&f(n)\\
0&1\\
1&6\\
2&18\\
3&40\\
4&75\\
5&126\\
6&196\\
7&288\\
8&405\\
9&550\\
10&726\\
11&936\\
12&1183\\
13&1470\\
14&1800\\
15&2176\\
16&2601\\
17&3078\\
18&3610\\
19&4200\\
20&4851
\end{matrix}$$

So it looks like you get the formula for $n$ sequences of $3$ elements is:

$$\frac{2}{(n+1)^2(n+2)}\binom{3n}{n,n,n}$$

---

For interleaving sequences of four elements, XYZW, you seem to get:

$$\frac{12}{(n+1)^3(n+2)^2(n+3)}\binom{4n}{n,n,n,n}$$

---

For sequences with five elements, the value seems to be:

$$\frac{288}{(n+1)^4(n+2)^3(n+3)^2(n+4)}\binom{5n}{n,n,n,n,n}$$

OEIS told me the sequence $1,2,12,288$ was the superfactorial sequence, which means:

$$1=1!, 2=2!1!, 12=3!2!1!, 288=4!3!2!1!$$

For that, I got my conjectured answer at the top.

Comment: Good investigation